# Can't login using HTMLUNIT - JAVA

Tags: java, authentication

i've spend about 3 hours trying to figure it out why can't i login to facebook using HTML unit but with no success. If you can help me , that would be great....Thanks in advance.

```html
package loginautomatically;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginAutomatically {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
       final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
      
       webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
   
       

final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.facebook.com");
final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("login_form");

final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0); // in my country, this button is named as: 
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
textField.setValueAttribute("myaddress@yahoo.com"); //address used to login to facebook
final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
textField2.setValueAttribute("mypassword"); //facebook password
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    
//this is what i get when using inspect element on facebook page

 // <input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1">

//<input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="2">

// button -> <label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="loginbutton" for="u_0_v"><input value="Conectează-te" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="u_0_v"></label>

//<input value="Conectează-te" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="u_0_v"> 

//Conectează-te -> this can be translated into english by "log in" (this is the button) 



    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i forgot to mention , the error i'm getting while compiling this snippet is (i'm using netbeans):                  run:
Sep 25, 2015 12:16:20 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input
Sep 25, 2015 12:16:20 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input

Comment: Anyone...? :D a little example + what i've done wrong would help a lot, thanks ! Do i need to add something else to the library in classpath ? Or my code is not good ?